# Struggle in *ngIf in angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular9, angular-ng-if

I am trying to add `site1Sec.length < 1` into `*ngIf`

.component.ts

```
site1Sec = [];
site2Sec = [];
```

.html

```
<nb-step *ngFor="let selectedSite of selectedSiteOptions" [label]="selectedSite.name">
                            <ng-template #selectedSite.name>{{selectedSite.name}} </ng-template>
                            <!-- inside each sites -->
                            <div class="row no-gutters my-3 justify-content-end w-100"
                                >
                                <button nbButton class="new-btn" status="primary"
                                *ngIf="selectedSite.code+'Sec'.length < 1"        
                                 [id]="selectedSite.name"
                                (click)="onSectionAddHandler(selectedSite.id)"
                                [id]="selectedSite.id"
                                    size="small">
                                    Add New Section
                                </button>
                            </div>
// removed
```

`*ngIf="selectedSite.code+'Sec'.length < 1"`  this is wrong It take as length of string value (length is 3).
How can I bind `site1Sec` , `site2Sec`,......

I need

```
*ngIf="site1Sec.length < 1"  // if site1 is selected
*ngIf="site2Sec.length < 1"  // if site2 is selected

*ngIf="site3Sec.length < 1"  // if site3 is selected 
// and so on
```

please anyone give a solution

Answer (score 1):

Create a method on your component:

```
public getSiteSec(siteCode: string) {
  return this[siteCode + 'Sec'];
}
```

I was researching if `this` keyword is accessible from template but didn't found the answer. Since I'm on mobile right now I can't test it. So I'm suggesting using a method to do it.

**Edit**

Just answering my own question and providing a better answer:

You can access `this` keyword within your template, so you can just do:

```
*ngIf="this[selectedSite.code+'Sec'].length < 1"
```